# openCV inRange masking

Tags: opencv, masking

I'm using Opencv 3.0 to get only the colored objects in an image. Therefore i create and use a mask.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Orignial", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Mask", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    // First load your image
    Mat mSrc = imread("IMG_0005_AUSZUG2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat mGray = Mat::zeros(mSrc.size(), mSrc.type());
    cvtColor(mSrc, mGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // define your mask
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(mSrc.size(), mSrc.type());

    // define destination image
    Mat dstImg = Mat::zeros(mSrc.size(), mSrc.type());

    //finding mask
    inRange(mSrc, Scalar(90, 90, 90), Scalar(180, 180, 180), mask);

    // combination of mask and Source image
    dilate(mask, mask, Mat(), Point(-1, -1));
    bitwise_not(mask, mask);
    //cvtColor(mask, mask, CV_GRAY2BGR);
    mSrc.copyTo(dstImg, mask);
    //bitwise_and(mSrc, mSrc, dstImg, mask);

    imshow("Mask", mask);
    imshow("Orignial", mSrc);
    imshow("Display", dstImg);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the result image is not the intended one. Only the colored objects should stay, because they have a white background in the mask, but it seems that the result image is a combination of source and mask.

Anybody know how to fix this ?

Source:

[image: Source]

Mask:

[image: Mask]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Picture of the mask https://ibb.co/nyHnbv

Comment: Before the `copyTo`, `dstImg` is all zeros -- i.e. all black. `copyTo` will modify only the areas where the mask is white -- the rest remains as it was before, i.e. all black.

Answer (score 1):

To understand your requirement- you have an image with some coloured objects in it, in a white background, and you essentially want an result image containing the same coloured objects in a black background instead.

If that's the case, `inRange` will not help because you've essentially kept the threshold between grey values `90` and `180`, so your code will discard dark objects as well.

To ensure that you obtain a mask **that is black only in the white background regions**, I would suggest using the `threshold` function instead, as shown:

```
//finding mask
//inRange(mSrc, Scalar(90, 90, 90), Scalar(180, 180, 180), mask);
threshold(mGray, mask, 220, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

This function will ensure that any pixel value in your greyscale image above `220` will be set to 0 in the binary mask.

To superimpose the binary mask over the source image, you should use the `subtract` method, as shown:

```
cvtColor(mask,mask,CV_GRAY2BGR);//change thresh to a 3 channel image

Mat mResult = Mat::zeros(mSrc.size(), mSrc.type());

subtract(mask,mSrc,mResult);
subtract(mask,mResult,mResult);
```